# How to use lineno with amsmath align?

Tags: align, amsmath, line-numbering, lineno

Is there a way to have `lineno` show line numbers for a paragraph that uses the `align` environment?

In the following example, the (first) paragraph that ends with `\begin{align} ... \end{align}` does not have the desired line numbers, whereas the (second) paragraph that separates the text with a single new line contains the line numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\linenumbers
\title{My Document}
\author{Anonymous Anteater}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\begin{align}
x = 2
\end{align}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis

\begin{align}
x = 2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: missing line numbers with lineno and align]

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Why doesn't `lineno` number a paragraph when it is followed by an `align` equation environment without a space?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43648/5764)

Comment: @Werner apologies for the duplicate, shall I close my question?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `lineno` package is not compatible with the `amsmath` environments, but the two can be made to work together.
Without the `mathlines` option to `lineno` (which turns on line numbering inside equations) this is pretty simple, but if you want the lines inside equations to be numbered it becomes a little more difficult.

#### Manual fix (without `mathlines` only)

The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/lineno/lineno.pdf) for [`lineno`](https://ctan.org/pkg/lineno) describes how to get the equation numbering around a display equation right:

> `lineno.sty` does not work well with display math. The parts of a
> paragraph preceeding a display math will not get line numbers. The
> reason is that the paragraph is not finished, but the part above the
> display is broken into lines anyway.
>
> […]
>
> `lineno.sty` defines a `{linenomath}` environment, which can be wrapped around a display math to make the line numbering work. This will work with any kind of display math, even if you use explicit `$$` pairs. There is a *-form `{linenomath*}` which also numbers the lines of the display itself, as good as it can.

This works fine as long as you don't provide the `mathlines` option to `lineno` (which turns on line numbering inside equations) or use the starred form.

```
\begin{linenomath}
    \begin{align}
        …
    \end{align}
\end{linenomath}
```

Doing this for every equation is a bit of a hassle, though.

#### Automatic fix (without `mathlines`)

Instead of manually doing this for every equation, it is more convenient to patch the AMS math environments instead.
This can be done by adding the following (or some variation of it) to the preamble.

```
\usepackage{lineno}   %% <- no mathlines option
\usepackage{amsmath}  %% <- after lineno
\usepackage{etoolbox} %% <- for \cspreto, \csappto

%% Patch 'normal' math environments:
\newcommand*\linenomathpatch[1]{%
  \cspreto{#1}{\linenomath}%
  \cspreto{#1*}{\linenomath}%
  \csappto{end#1}{\endlinenomath}%
  \csappto{end#1*}{\endlinenomath}%
}

\linenomathpatch{equation}
\linenomathpatch{gather}
\linenomathpatch{multline}
\linenomathpatch{align}
\linenomathpatch{alignat}
\linenomathpatch{flalign}
```

This also won't work well if the `mathlines` option to `lineno` is used (see below).

Note: The choice to load `lineno` *before* `amsmath` was intentional because `lineno` also patches the `equation` environment (but not `equation*`), as well as `\[`+`\]` (somewhat improperly), while `amsmath` redefines them completely.
If the packages are loaded in the opposite order, `equation` and `\[`+`\]` end up being patched twice (which is harmless) and `\[`+`\]` ends up no longer being robust.
Since `\[` and `\]` are defined as shorthands for `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}`, these do work fine for this order.

#### Automatic fix (with or without `mathlines`)

If you are using the `mathlines` option to `lineno` because you also want the lines of the equations themselves to be numbered, there are some problems with this approach.
An additional line number will be printed just below all `amsmath` equation environment, and `multline` will additionally receive an extra line number at the top.
I posted a way to avoid both of these extraneous line numbers in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443201/156366) to [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436011/156366).

You'll need to add the following to the preamble of your document.
If the `mathlines` options is removed this will still work, but lines inside equations will no longer be numbered.

```
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno} %% <- with [mathlines] to number lines in equations
\usepackage{amsmath}           %% <- after lineno
\usepackage{etoolbox}          %% <- for \cspreto, \csappto and \patchcmd

%% Patch 'normal' math environments:
\newcommand*\linenomathpatch[1]{%
  \cspreto{#1}{\linenomath}%
  \cspreto{#1*}{\linenomath}%
  \csappto{end#1}{\endlinenomath}%
  \csappto{end#1*}{\endlinenomath}%
}
%% Patch AMS math environments:
\newcommand*\linenomathpatchAMS[1]{%
  \cspreto{#1}{\linenomathAMS}%
  \cspreto{#1*}{\linenomathAMS}%
  \csappto{end#1}{\endlinenomath}%
  \csappto{end#1*}{\endlinenomath}%
}

%% Definition of \linenomathAMS depends on whether the mathlines option is provided
\expandafter\ifx\linenomath\linenomathWithnumbers
  \let\linenomathAMS\linenomathWithnumbers
  %% The following line gets rid of an extra line numbers at the bottom:
  \patchcmd\linenomathAMS{\advance\postdisplaypenalty\linenopenalty}{}{}{}
\else
  \let\linenomathAMS\linenomathNonumbers
\fi

\linenomathpatch{equation}
\linenomathpatchAMS{gather}
\linenomathpatchAMS{multline}
\linenomathpatchAMS{align}
\linenomathpatchAMS{alignat}
\linenomathpatchAMS{flalign}

% Disable line numbering during measurement step of multline
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\mmeasure@}{\measuring@true}{
  \measuring@true
  \ifnum-\linenopenaltypar>\interdisplaylinepenalty
    \advance\interdisplaylinepenalty-\linenopenalty
  \fi
  }{}{}
\makeatother
```

An explanation of why all of this is necessary and why this works can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443201/156366).

---

### Demonstration

Here is a sample document for the last solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno} %% <- remove [mathlines] to omit equation line numbers
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{etoolbox} %% <- for \pretocmd, \apptocmd and \patchcmd

%% Patch 'normal' math environments:
\newcommand*\linenomathpatch[1]{%
  \cspreto{#1}{\linenomath}%
  \cspreto{#1*}{\linenomath}%
  \csappto{end#1}{\endlinenomath}%
  \csappto{end#1*}{\endlinenomath}%
}
%% Patch AMS math environments:
\newcommand*\linenomathpatchAMS[1]{%
  \cspreto{#1}{\linenomathAMS}%
  \cspreto{#1*}{\linenomathAMS}%
  \csappto{end#1}{\endlinenomath}%
  \csappto{end#1*}{\endlinenomath}%
}

%% Definition of \linenomathAMS depends on whether the mathlines option is provided
\expandafter\ifx\linenomath\linenomathWithnumbers
  \let\linenomathAMS\linenomathWithnumbers
  %% The following line gets rid of an extra line numbers at the bottom:
  \patchcmd\linenomathAMS{\advance\postdisplaypenalty\linenopenalty}{}{}{}
\else
  \let\linenomathAMS\linenomathNonumbers
\fi

\linenomathpatch{equation}
\linenomathpatchAMS{gather}
\linenomathpatchAMS{multline}
\linenomathpatchAMS{align}
\linenomathpatchAMS{alignat}
\linenomathpatchAMS{flalign}

\linenumbers
\title{My Document}
\author{Anonymous Anteater}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\begin{align*}
    \nabla \cdot E &= \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}
    &
    \nabla \times E &= - \frac{\partial B}{\partial t}
    \\
    \nabla \cdot B &= 0
    &
    \nabla \times B &= \mu_0 J + \mu_0 \varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial E}{\partial t}
\end{align*}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis

\begin{equation*}
    (\mathrm{id}_{C} \otimes \Delta ) \circ \Delta = (\Delta \otimes \mathrm{id}_{C}) \circ \Delta
\end{equation*}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor,
\[
    \bigwedge_{i=1}^{\dim(V)} A(v_i) = \det(A) \bigwedge_{i=1}^{\dim(V)} v_i,
\]
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to extend this to work with `\[ ... \]` display math as well?

Comment: @PeterGrill I modified the answer to obey (the presence/absence of) the `mathlines` option. With this option `\[…\]`-equations are also counted as lines.

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't notice that you had removed the `mathlines` option in your MWE.

Comment: @PeterGrill I thought it was no longer necessary, but I had forgotten about `\[…\]`.

Comment: Just noticed that you are missing the trailing `%` in the `\linenomathpatch@`, `\linenomathpatch@AMS` and the usage of `\linenomathpatch`. These don't matter if the patching is all done in the preamble, but if for some reason a user decides to apply the patch to only a portion of the doc, they will be spurious spaces.

Comment: @PeterGrill good point, I fixed it.

Comment: They are also needed _after_ each `\linenomathpatch{}%`

Comment: @PeterGrill I don't quite agree that this is necessary. These would be different from the line breaks I just commented out because they are not *inside* a definition. Adding a `%` after each `\linenomathpatchAMS{…}` would be similar to appending a `%` to every `\newcommand` in your preamble, which I think only very few people do. It only matters if someone copies these lines and places them somewhere mid-paragraph without removing or commenting out line breaks.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense.

Comment: example would be improved by a multi-line `align`.  `align` isn't meant to be used for single-line formulas.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I changed the example to include a multi-line `align` environment.

Comment: @Circumscribe -- thanks.  seeing a line number on both lines is something i haven't seen before.  i'll have to try it out with the other `amsmath` multi-line environments.

Comment: This seems to work with `align` but not `alignat`

Comment: You need to also patch equation if amsmath is loaded because then equation gets changed (and `equation*` was never patched before)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: Thanks, you're right. I hadn't realised `equation*` wasn't already patched by `lineno`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Circumscribe there is that but also equation is no longer patched (I think) if amsmath is loaded after lineno

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: Before my edit earlier today I was loading `amsmath` *before* `lineno` precisely for that reason, but I swapped the order to avoid patching `equation` twice since I'm patching `equation` myself now.

Comment: Very nice and useful suggestion....

Comment: The last two `\cspreto` in `\linenomathpatch` should be `\csappto`, as the `\linenomathpatchAMS` below. Otherwise this may cause some unexpected `Overfull \vbox` in the document.

Comment: @Jinwen, you're absolutely right, I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to replace the `align` by

```
\[
  \begin{aligned}
    x = 2
  \end{aligned}
\]
```

or by

```
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
   x = 2
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

if you want numbered version.

[image]

Comment: example would be improved by a multi-line `aligned`.  `aligned` isn't meant to be used for single-line formulas.