# Environment with its own line numbers

Tags: environments, line-numbering

I would like to create an environment with its own line numbers, that is to say:

(1) the lines within this environment are **not** counted by `lineno`

(2) it has a continuous line numbering itself, *with displayed equations numbered*

Thus, say this environment has the name `MYenv`, I would like this:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lineno} % here I didn't use [mathlines]

\begin{document}
    \linenumbers

    TEXT

    \begin{MYenv}
        TEXT \[x\] TEXT
    \end{MYenv}

    TEXT

    \[y\]

    \begin{MYenv}
        TEXT
    \end{MYenv}
\end{document}
```

to produce something like

```
1    | TEXT
MY1  | TEXT
MY2  | x
MY3  | TEXT
2    | TEXT
     | y
MY4  | TEXT
```

How should one define such an environment?

Answer (score 1):

The code below defines a conditional `\ifLNturnsON` to record whether line numbers have been turned on in the context. Inside `MYenv` it uses the counter `myLN` to store the line numbers in this environment. It also stores the value of counter `linenumber` in `recordLN`, and restores the normal line numbers after `MYenv`, so that the main text and the environment `MYenv` have separate line numbers.

As for the numbering for displayed math, it uses a patch from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461192). The environment `MYenv` numbers displayed math with `\linenumberdisplaymath`, no matter whether `[mathlines]` option has been turned on in the main text. Thus in the example below, you can see that displayed math has been numbered (`\[x\]`) inside `MYenv`, but not in the main text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lineno}

\newif\ifLNturnsON

\newcounter{recordLN}
\newcounter{myLN}
\setcounter{myLN}{1}

\renewcommand\makeLineNumber{\hss\scriptsize\ttfamily \LineNumber~$|$\hspace{1em}}%

\newenvironment{MYenv}
{%
\setcounter{recordLN}{\value{linenumber}}%
\setcounter{linenumber}{\value{myLN}}%
\LNturnsONfalse%
\ifLineNumbers\LNturnsONtrue\fi\nolinenumbers%
\linenumbers%
\renewcommand\makeLineNumber{\hss\scriptsize\ttfamily MY \LineNumber~$|$\hspace{1em}}%
\linenumberdisplaymath% number displayed math
}
{%
\par%
\ifLNturnsON\linenumbers\fi%
\setcounter{myLN}{\value{linenumber}}%
\setcounter{linenumber}{\value{recordLN}}%
}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}

%% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461192
% Patch 'normal' math environments:
\newcommand*\linenomathpatch[1]{%
    \cspreto{#1}{\linenomath}%
    \cspreto{#1*}{\linenomath}%
    \cspreto{end#1}{\endlinenomath}%
    \cspreto{end#1*}{\endlinenomath}%
}
% Patch AMS math environments:
\newcommand*\linenomathpatchAMS[1]{%
    \cspreto{#1}{\linenomathAMS}%
    \cspreto{#1*}{\linenomathAMS}%
    \csappto{end#1}{\endlinenomath}%
    \csappto{end#1*}{\endlinenomath}%
}
% Define \linenomathAMS depending on whether 'mathlines' option is provided
\expandafter\ifx\linenomath\linenomathWithnumbers
    \let\linenomathAMS\linenomathWithnumbers
% The following line gets rid of an extra line numbers at the bottom:
    \patchcmd\linenomathAMS{\advance\postdisplaypenalty\linenopenalty}{}{}{}
\else
    \let\linenomathAMS\linenomathNonumbers
\fi

\linenomathpatch{equation}
\linenomathpatchAMS{gather}
\linenomathpatchAMS{multline}
\linenomathpatchAMS{align}
\linenomathpatchAMS{alignat}
\linenomathpatchAMS{flalign}


\usepackage[skip=0pt]{parskip}

\begin{document}
    \linenumbers

    TEXT

    \begin{MYenv}
        TEXT \[x\] TEXT
    \end{MYenv}

    TEXT

    \[y\]

    \begin{MYenv}
        TEXT
    \end{MYenv}
\end{document}
```