# How to detect if a certain patch has been made?

Tags: etoolbox

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461192/194994) offers a nice patch to allow `lineno` works fine with `amsmath` environments, and I would like to use this in some of my classes and styles that use `lineno`. However, this may cause the patch applied multiple times. Is there anyway to detect if the patch has already been made?

Comment: Oh, I was being stupid. `\ifdefined\linenomathpatch` will do the work.